# Datetime range picker for angularjs version 1.2.13

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I am developing a website in angularjs 1.2.13.Now I need a date time range picker to set the start date and expiry for a product.I googled in a number of sites.But I didn't get a plugin for angular version 1.2.13.If anybody knows the plugin work in angular version 1.2.13 please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have recently made a simple date range picker(does not include time). You may use it and modify it as per your requirement. Link: https://github.com/26avantika/datepickerRange

Comment: Its good .But I need time also

Comment: If you have the time and idea, feel free to modify it and send a pull request

Comment: [UIB timepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#timepicker) and [UIB datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker).

Comment: I need a date time range picker to select start date,time and expiry date,time

Comment: If you can use jQuery, here's my plugin that can help you : https://codecanyon.net/item/calentim-date-time-range-picker/20099228